# In R, how do you subset rows of a dataframe based on values in a vector

Tags: r, filter, subset

I'd like to generate a subset based on factor values contained in a vector. I've included my working code for a simple example. However, what if I have many columns (>10) and I don't wish to list each column using "|" (OR), is there a better way to do this? My example below uses LETTERS but I am dealing with factors (people's names).

```
set.seed(37)
df <- data.frame(id1=sample(LETTERS, 20),id2=sample(LETTERS, 20))
L <- c("A","B","E")
subset(df, id1 %in% L | id2 %in% L )
   id1 id2
2    B   V
10   C   B
11   F   A
14   A   F
19   E   S
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` to construct the *OR* condition:

```
subset(df, Reduce("|", lapply(df, `%in%`, L)))

#   id1 id2
#2    B   V
#10   C   B
#11   F   A
#14   A   F
#19   E   S
```

---

Or use `rowSums` to check if there is any letter matching in each row:

```
subset(df, rowSums(sapply(df, `%in%`, L)) != 0)

#   id1 id2
#2    B   V
#10   C   B
#11   F   A
#14   A   F
#19   E   S
```

Comment: Or an option with `data.table` `setDT(df)[df[, Reduce('|', lapply(.SD, `%in%`, L))]]`

Comment: looks like it should be '%in%' (in quotes).

Answer (score 1):

```
df[sort(unique(unlist(lapply(df, function(x) which(x %in% L))))),]
#   id1 id2
#2    B   V
#10   C   B
#11   F   A
#14   A   F
#19   E   S
```